# ExtJS: check window state (is minimized, is maximized, etc)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

ExtJS provides a number of configs as to whether a Window is configured as
[maximized](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-maximized),  [minimizable](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-minimizable), etc. It also provides the functions to [maximize](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-maximize) and [minimize](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-minimize) a window.

Can't find however what the correct way to *fetch an existing window state* is. What I need is functions similar to the below:

```
var myWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', { ... });
...
myWin.isMinimized(); // is current window minimized?
myWin.isMaximized(); // is current window maximized?
```

Can the current window's state be retrieved from the window instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [`maximize()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Window.html#Ext-window-Window-method-maximize) there is a boolean property `maximized` which you can pick up from an object:

```
if (myWin.maximized) { ... }
```

However for [`minimize()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Window.html#Ext-window-Window-method-minimize) ExtJS doesn't provide any functionality and expects individual implementation. Hence, there is no any `minimized` property supported from the box.

Answer (score 1):

@VisioN's answer is already complete but I want to show you a snippet using [`toggleCollapse()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-toggleCollapse) to hide the window:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Window',{
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    minimizable: true,
    listeners: {
        minimize: function(){
            var win = this;
            win.toggleCollapse();
            if (!win.getCollapsed()) {
                win.center();
            } else {
                win.alignTo(document.body, 'bl-bl');
            }
        }
    }
}).show();
```

Comment: what is `toggleCollapse()`? it is giving error for me. If it is userdefined, then plz provide code for it

Comment: Which version of ExtJs are you running? It is available since: 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

One solution for anyone looking, instead of using `minimizable` config, use `tools`. Here is complete example..

```
var isMinimized = false;   //if you want to check for minimized elsewhere..
var winWidth;          //to restore to actual width.
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    closable : false,
    width : 300, height : 400,
     tools: [
                {  
                    type: 'restore',
                    hidden : true,
                    handler: function( evt,toolEl,owner,tool ) {
                        var window = owner.up( 'window' );
                        window.expand('',false);
                     window.setWidth(winWidth);
                        window.center();
                        isMinimized = false;
                        this.hide();
                        this.nextSibling().show();
                    }                                
                },{  
                    type: 'minimize',
                    handler: function( evt,toolEl,owner,tool ){
                        var window = owner.up( 'window' );
                        window.collapse();
                        winWidth = window.getWidth();
                        window.setWidth( 150 );
                        window.alignTo( Ext.getBody(), 'bl-bl');
                        this.hide();
                        this.previousSibling().show();
                        isMinimized = true;
                    }                                
                }                            
            ]
}).show();
```

Comment: This is a really good solution. What happens if don't want overlaps when you minimize different windows?